# Can an EVA kill it's pilot through harm caused during battle?

Tags: neon-genesis-evangelion

One of the big flaws in the EVA Systems is the issue of the EVA's nervous system connecting and interacting with the nervous system of the pilot. During the manga and the anime, it is shown time and time again that the injuries incurred to the EVA during combat are transferred to the pilot as well, a good example being Zeruel blasting EVA Unit 01's hand off, and Shinji feeling the pain of said action.

Now, this got me thinking, obviously the amount of pain endured would send any normal person in shock, due to multiple factors, like blood loss and outright "pain". If an EVA is seriously damaged during a battle, wouldn't the shock of the "pain and injuries" be enough to kill the pilot?

A very graphic example is Asuka and EVA Unit 02 vs the Mass production Evangelion Units, paying close attention to the sheer amount of damage Unit 02 sustained during the battle, being disemboweled and so on, eventually killing the EVA Unit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After doing some reading on the Evangelion Wikis, I stumbled upon an article that answers this question.

An Evangelion can kill it's pilot with shock from the injuries, and therefore Central Command has to watch the sync rate between the pilot and the Unit to ensure that the pilot does not die during combat, as was nearly the case with Unit 02 and Asuka vs Zeruel.

Source --> https://wiki.evageeks.org/Evangelions (See The Effect of Damage to the Evas upon their Pilots)